# Python is aliased to Python 3 but facing error in make file

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, zsh

I'm using zsh and I'm trying to install some dependencies of a external project. Currently I'm trying to alias python to python3 and in my `./zshrc` file, I've included the line to make the alias:

.zshrc

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/me/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

alias python="python3"
```

After running `source ~/.zshrc`, checking python versions return me the following:

```
which python
python: aliased to python3

which python3
/opt/hombrew/bin/python3
```

However, when I try in the external project to install dependencies, it throws me an error saying that my python is not pointing to Python 3:

```
The python command does not point to Python 3
make: *** [check_python] Error 1
```

The make file that is throwing the error:

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) clean_output
    @$(MAKE) clean_build
    @$(MAKE) buildS
    @$(MAKE) clean_build
    @$(MAKE) buildX
    @$(MAKE) clean_build
    @$(MAKE) buildS2

.PHONY: check_python
check_python:
    @python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(3-sys.version_info.major)' || (echo "The python command does not point to Python 3"; exit 1)
```

I've checked the output of `3-sys.version_info.major` and it returns `0`

I would like to check  - am I aliasing my python correctly?

Comment: Aliases are valid only within the shell, but the `make` probably uses other shell than you: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html .

Comment: I see. If ```make``` uses bash, do I have to set the alias in ```.bashrc``` then ?

Comment: It is a little bit complicated: `.bashrc` is for interactive shells. For non-interacitve shells you need to define `BASH_ENV` pointing to a file with the aliases. Anyway, I would prefer a symlink `python -> python3` in `/usr/bin` provided that you don't have any old python2 software that could break.

Comment: You should just use `python3` in your makefile.  If you really can't do that, then create a script `~/bin/python` which invokes `python3` and ensure that `$HOME/bin` is on your `PATH` before anything else.  Adding a symlink to your `/usr/bin` directory is a bad idea in general since that directory is owned by the distribution and its package manager and this could cause problems with future package installs.

Comment: You define the alias in your current zsh process. This process creates a child process for `make`  and _make_ itself tries to create a python process. _make_ can't have any knowledge about what you are doing in your zsh parent. In fact, make does not care whether it is called as a child of zsh (has aliases) or of a Tcl or Fortran program  (do not have aliases). If inside `make`, you have to restrict yourself to those features _make_ is giving you.